# How to ignore 1st touch event when screensaver is enabled

Tags: windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact

on our Win CE 6.0 device (x86 platform), screensaving is enabled using the 
Powermanager UserIdle Timeout:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\Timeouts]
    "ACUserIdle"=dword:3c

My assumption is, the graphics driver (Intel iegd) listens to this event and turns on/off backlight accordingly.

The problem is, when screensaving is enabled (backlight is off), the 1st touch event is already utilized by the windows system.
In other words, the user touches the touch screen while backlight is off, and accidentally/blindly triggers some action on any running application (eg press some buttons...).

We don't have sources for the touch driver (TSHARC USB), so changes can't be made here.

Are there any other ways to discard the 1st touch event while backlight is off?
Where is a good place to look at?

Thanks in advance for any help / suggestions.
Regards, Timm

Comment: I just quicky tested an application on CE 6.0. When i touch the screen to disable the screensaver it does not activate a touch event on the application.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I think this is system dependent, i.e. depending on how the screen saver/display driver are implemented.
On our system, touch events are generated while screen-saver is active.